# How do we Clear Controller And Model cache in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, caching

I have very simple application in Laravel 5.5.

```
My Route : Route::resource('books', 'BookController');
My Controller is app/http/Controllers/BookController.php
My Model is app/Book.php
```

I have similar other modules as well.

INTERESTING PART IS :

My Book controller changes are not being reflected in browser.

I thought of clearing the cache so cleared all caches.

```
1. Cleared Application Cache > php artisan cache:clear
2. Cleared Route Cache > php artisan route:clear
3. Cleared Configuration Cache > php artisan config:clear 
4. Cleared Compiled Views Cache > php artisan view:clear
```

I was not sure which cache was causing the issue so I cleared all.
Still my changes are not being reflected in the browser, but when I change
the view files, the changes are being reflected.

Any Suggestion please?????

Comment: Could you please show the output and the relevant code so that we may help you better.

Comment: Actually, I have deleted the BookController.php file itself and even though all the functionality are working. :(

Comment: is it at local? or at production?

Comment: Also comment the resource **books** and let me know if it still does not update.

Comment: It looks like silly thing, but have you verify that you are editing the correct file? You might have a duplicate file by mistake with a similar name.

Comment: Its in the production. My local changes are being reflected. And when I comment the route, it does not work.

Comment: Yes @KaushikThakkar, unfortunately I am editing the correct file but the changes are not being reflected. Does Laravel makes a copy of controller file as well??

Comment: Also interesting thing that I noticed is if I change the controller name to NewBookContorller.php and load that file in route, then everything works fine. :(

Comment: Is it still occuring Or did you solve it?

Comment: What I think is if you are pulling changes on production through git Or any other vcs do check the gitignore and please check the file by opening it on production server if it takes up the correct changes

Answer (score 6):

Finally I guess I have found the solutions.
All the files are being cached in this location

```
/home/project/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
where project = project name
```

So if we change the file name, then we need to run the following commands.

```
php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
```

Since the above bug ruins my past 2 days, so I guess its worth sharing
for someone having the same issue or problem.

**Please correct me if above solution can be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for cache clear in your laravel project.

php artisan cache: clear.
php artisan config: clear.
php artisan cache: clear

Answer (score 0):

If in your model use trait Cachable, but you want to test the changed data on last record you called before. Let comment line code "use Cachable".